# Temperature conversion android tutorial part 10.7 trouble

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i am following this tutorial:

```
 http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#first_start
```

but when i come to step 10.7 i right click on the project->Run As->Android Application
It comes up with a popup stating: No Compatible targets found,Do you wish to add a new AVD.

I click yes, and launch a new AVD and click start
The device comes up BUT nowhere is there a sign of my app??
The android device chooser then at the top have: Select a device compatible with android 4.0.3??? i edit it and select 4.0.3 but then get error:

```
[2012-03-07 09:25:21 - SDK Manager] Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi to copy into the AVD folder.
```

I am running eclipse galileo
i dont understand.
can someone help please?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because .. you just have downloaded the 4.0.3 sdk and not "ARM EABI v7a System Image" from the android sdk manager... once you do this.. your problem will b solved...

Comment: now EVERYTHING under 4.0.3 is installed and i get the same problem :(

Comment: ok.. in your eclipse.. go to FILE---->Switch Workspace--> and tell what folders are there..

Comment: it just says Other... and when i click on there it shows /home/helloises/android_app

Comment: ok... 1st ithink u should restart eclipse after you have installed "ARM EABI v7a System Image"... so today it should work for you... if it doesn't... create a new workspace folder by clicking on "Other" in file-->switchworkspace..then make the same project as you did earlier..and try then...

Comment: at last! it works..i re did the whole thing and deleted the previous project! thanks very much!